# Join Two Queries/Select Statement

Tags: sql, select, join

I don't know how to explain it. But I am trying to join two select statements/queries. I need to include customer and supplier name in the same table.

```
Table 1 - j:
Job ID, Customer ID
Table 2 - jl:
Job_Line.Job_ID, Supplier_ID
Table 3 - p:
ID, Name
```

First Select statement - customer name:

```
Select name
From p
INNER JOIN j ON p.id = j.customer_id
```

Second Select statement - supplier name:

```
Select name
From p
INNER JOIN jl ON p.id = jl.supplier_id
```

Don't know how to join above two selects, so i could have a table like:

```
id, customer name, supplier name
```

I am new to SQL and learning online. I understand the basis, but getting stuck at this finding this complex!

Comment: What does `p` contain? The name of the customer? The name of the supplier? Both? Do you use different IDs in the `p` table for customers and suppliers? This schema looks terrible to me

Comment: @Jcl, indeed that seems to be the case, based on the selects Honhaar provided, I totally agree with you that the schema looks bad.

Comment: yes p contains names of customer, supplier, managers and many more!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
SELECT j.id, pc.name, ps.name
FROM j
INNER JOIN p pc ON j.customer_id = pc.id
INNER JOIN jl ON j.id = jl.job_id
INNER JOIN p ps ON jl.supplier_id = ps.id
```

Note, pc and ps are table aliases.

Comment: In the case of same customer done multiple job with different- different supplier the above query is not working properly. It returns wrong output.

Comment: Thanks, I spent entire day to do this!! Each job is unique.